# How to undo the last changes to a custom menu?

Tags: menus, customization

I have a wordpress site with a custom menu. When I want to add a page or something to the menu, I click appearance, add the item, then drag it to the right location. This time when I did it the menu only saved about 30% of what was originally there. Normally, I would be just a little annoyed to have to rebuild the menu, but in this case, it is a pretty extensive menu with over a hundred items.

Is there a way to undo the most recent menu save?

---

Possibly necessary details:

- Wordpress 4.4.1
- Custom theme, custom menu

Comment: I had to do a restore to fix the issue and only use the customizer now when editing the menu. The problem has not repeated.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, there is no native way undo menu changes. However I did find this plugin [Menus History](https://wordpress.org/plugins/menus-history/), however I haven't tested it and it will only save changes in the future

Comment: The problem seems deeper than a bad save. I cannot add any more items to the menu at all, so I can't even fix it manually.

Comment: It looks like the plugin iMember360 is interfering with it. I deactivated it and now I can save menu items again. I guess I need to talk to their support.

Comment: Scratch that. It just did it again, but the plugin is still deactivated.

Comment: @fredsbend try deactivating all plugins and then try saving your menu. Then reactivate your plugins one by one.

Comment: All plugins deactivated and still not able to add items.

Comment: Here's a plus one for helping.

Comment: That is odd then. I'd say it's something in the theme then, but I generally wouldn't expect so from a custom theme. Is it just one specific menu that is broken or all menus?

Comment: There is only one menu on the site.

Comment: Create a new menu, just don't assign it anywhere and see if the new menu is also affected

Comment: Also, see if it affects just the menu editing page, or the menu editor in the customizer as well

Comment: Customizer seems to work.

Comment: I was going to try [this](http://sevenspark.com/wordpress/menu-item-limit#solution), but I guess I need to ask my host to reset apache.